# Possible to have 2 unity launchers?

Tags: unity, launcher

Is it possible to have 2 unity launchers? One on the Left and one on the Right. In my thoughts, the Left one (The Default) would have the normal stuff that i use everyday. The Right side would have additional stuff that i might use like wine programs or to show the recent documents. Just some ideas to my reason to having 2 panels. Is it possible/optional?

Comment: Not possible at present, but it's an interesting idea. How about suggesting it to [Ubuntu Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/) or the [Ayatana Mailing List](https://lists.launchpad.net/ayatana/)?

Comment: Added to Brainstorm flueteflute - http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/28005/ Do not know if i did it ok.

Comment: You could do that using Kubuntu (KDE desktop). But today it is still impossible to have many Unity launchers. Why. Because you have the dash that allows you to quickly open applications. 
Know that the launcher's main purpose is to allow you to quickly open the frequently used applications and the dash to open other applications.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You only get the one launcher in Unity, but you can simulate a second one if you use a combination of AWN and DockbarX with the appropriate theming. This is how I got a Unity-like interface on my 10.04 LTS desktop before 11.04 came out. The advantage of this is that the second panel that you created is then fully customizable, so you can create the setup you have just described.

DockbarX is not available to install from the default Ubuntu repositories, so I'll show you a way to simulate a second launcher using only AWN, which is available right from the Ubuntu Software Center. I did the steps below on my Precise Pangolin install, but you should be able to follow them on 11.10 as well and most likely older releases.

## Simulating a second launcher with AWN

Our goal is to get a second launcher on the right, as pictured below:

[image: Picture of the desired result]

First, we need AWN (Avant Window Navigator) installed. Click [here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/avant-window-navigator) to install it, or run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install avant-window-navigator
```

This should also install `awn-settings`, which will let you manage the settings for AWN.

Now start AWN Settings by searching for it in the dash, and let's start setting up the second launcher.

You'll get a window like that below:

[image: AWN Preferences]

Change all settings to those shown above.

Next, go to the Applets screen. We'll be using the below configuration (but feel free to modify as you please):

[image: AWN Applets]

The applets, from left to right (the ordering matters), are:

- **Cairo Main Menu**
- **Launcher/Taskmanager**
- **Related applet**
- **Shiny Switcher**
- **Expander** *(Needed to keep the previous applets near the top and the trash at the bottom)*
- **Garbage**

Next, go to Themes and select the **Dark Theme**. We'll use this as a base for the exact look we want.

Click the Customize button near the bottom of the window to enter this view:

[image: AWN Themes]

There's a lot of tweaking to do in here. Here are the following changes you need to make *(note: I listed colors as a hexadecimal value, or "Color name", and Opacity)*:

**Panel Colors**

- **First Gradient Color:** #000000, 170
- **Second Gradient Color:** #000000, 170
- **First Highlight Color:** #000000, 0
- **Second Highlight Color:** #000000, 0
- **Outer Border Color:** #808080, 100
- **Inner Border Color:** #000000, 0

**Tooltips**

- **Font:** Ubuntu 11
- **Fill Color:** #000000, 170
- **Outline Color:** #FFFFFF, 100

**Extras**

- **Arrow type:** Triangle

In case you're wondering: nope, still not quite done yet! There's some extra settings we need to take care of to position the launcher correctly; otherwise, it'll run over the menu bar at the top of the screen.

Now go into the Advanced screen:

[image: AWN Advanced]

Make sure **Force monitor mode?** is checked.

Now, make sure you set the following settings to what I've described below. If you don't know what your display resolution is, you can easily look it up by searching for "Displays" in the dash or System Settings.

- **Monitor width:** Your actual monitor width in pixels
- **Monitor height:** Your actual monitor height in pixels, minus 24
- **Monitor X-offset:** 0
- **Monitor Y-offset:** 24

For good measure, we should also set **Reflection alpha multiplier** to 0 while we're in here.

Almost done! We have a couple applet tweaks to make, if you decided to keep the Shiny Switcher and Garbage applets I suggested above so they're more like regular Unity. To enter the preferences for either applet, right-click it and select **Applet Preferences** from the pop-up menu.

### Shiny Switcher Preferences

Check that the settings are the same as those pictured (the colors selected are #000000, 255):

[image: Shiny Switcher Preferences Look]

[image: Shiny Switcher Preferences Behavior]

### Garbage Preferences

Keep **Confirm when emptying the trash** checked, but uncheck **Show the item count on the icon**.

> **One more note!** To test out your settings and make sure everything looks right, or if you did not set AWN to start automatically, search
> for "Avant Window Navigator" in the dash. I personally found that
> certain settings changes may require quitting AWN (via right-click on
> the dock itself) and restarting it in order for them to display
> properly.

Comment: I've remove the community wiki status since this isnt applicable.  It is a good answer - it would be a great answer if you can add a step by step guide with picture as to how this could be achieved.  thanks.

Comment: One warning about AWN, though.  You might find out that you like it better than Unity, and then you'll need to figure out how to get rid of Unity! :)  It doesn't have the new menubar, but other than that, it has some really nice features that Unity is missing.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately it's not possible to have more than one launcher in Unity.